# Using a SELECT statement with a searched CASE expression

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I created a table `scores` as follows.

```
student_id course score
1 math 90
1 cs 70
2 math 60
2 cs 50
```

I want to categorise all scores of a student by a scale:

```
>60 pass
<60 fail
=60 bottomline
```

Then, I wrote a select statement with a case expression as

```
select student_id, course, score =
(case score    
     when score > 60
     then 'pass'
     when score < 60
     then 'fail'
     else 'bottomline'
end) as 'result'
from scores
order by student_id
```

However, the result set looks like below, and the `result` column did not show categories as `pass`,
`fail`, or `bottomline` according to the scale. Instead, all the `result` values are `0`.

```
student_id course result
1 math 0
1 cs 0
2 math 0
2 cs 0
```

Where was I wrong with the select statement that caused all the `result` values to `0`? I am using a MySQL database server.

Comment: (what caused this problem?) I mixed up the syntax of a simple case expression and a searched case expression. In my case, I should use a searched case expression rather than a simple one. More information about the case expression can be found here: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select student_id, course, score,
   case                        --<-- you dont need to mention column name here
     when score < 60  then 'fail'
     when score = 60  then  'bottomline' 
     when score > 60  then 'pass'
   end as 'result'
from scores
order by student_id
```

## <kbd>[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/121dd/1)</kbd>

Comment: Include `score` as well in the query results

Answer (score 2):

why `score = ...` ?

just:

```
select student_id, course, score, 
(case score    
     when score > 60
     then 'pass'
     when score < 60
     then 'fail'
     else 'bottomline'
end) as 'result'
from scores
order by student_id
```

Comment: your modification shows all the `result` values to `bottomline`.

Comment: no `bottomline` will not be shown ever. but fail for all scores `<= 60`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SLELECT student_id, course,Score
   CASE  
     when score < 60  then 'fail'
     when score > 60  then 'pass'
   Else 'bottomline'
   END 'result'
FROM scores
ORDER BY student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This 
Create table scores (student_id int,course VARCHAR(100),score int);
Insert into scores values(1,'math',90);
Insert into scores values(1,'cs',70);
Insert into scores values(2,'math',60);
Insert into scores values(2,'cs',50);

Select student_id, course,score,
(case     
     when score > 60
     then 'pass'
     when score < 60
     then 'fail'
     else 'bottomline'
end) as 'result'
from scores
order by student_id;
```